# How I get Angular input field value?

Tags: angular, typescript

I successfully passed data to my form input field like below.

```
<div class="input" >
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="input-text">
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="" style=" width: 100%;" value="{{userDetail.name}}"  >
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

[Output without formControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7n1q.jpg)

I want to update and get this input field value to update the database. So I used "formControl" to get the input field value.

```
 [formControl]="nameControl"
```

But when I add this property I can't see the input field value. How I get this input field value?
[Output with formControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KJTx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can has a FormControl

```
control=new FormControl()

<!--see that not use value and use [formControl]-->
<input matInput placeholder="" style=" width: 100%;" [formControl]="control">
```

And then, you can give value when create the control

```
control=new FormControl('my value')
```

or using setValue

```
this.control.setValue('my value')
```

or you can has a formGroup and inside a FromControl

```
form=new FormGroup({
  control:new FormControl();
}))

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <!--see that not use value else FormControlName (without [])-->
  <input matInput placeholder="" style=" width: 100%;" formControlName="control">
</form>
```

Again, you can give value when create the form

```
form=new FormGroup({
  control:new FormControl('my value');
}))
```

or using setValue

```
this.form.setValue({control:'my value'}) //to all the form
//or
this.form.get('control').setValue('my value') //only to the control of the formControl
//you can also using patchValue
this.form.patchValue({control:'my value'}) //to all the form
```

Answer (score 0):

> `value="{{userDetail.name}}"`

interpolation on attribute it's a bad practice!  You should to use angular attribute and property binding instead:

- https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding
- https://angular.io/guide/property-binding

---

> How I get this input field value?

Angular provides two different approaches to handling user input through forms: reactive and template-drive.

### template-drive

```js
public name: string;
```

```html
<input matInput placeholder="" style=" width: 100%;" [(ngModel)]="name" />
```

### reactive

```js
public nameControl = new FormControl();
```

```html
<input matInput placeholder="" style=" width: 100%;" [formControl]="nameControl" />
```

---

in both cases, if you want to set an initial value, you have to do it yourself by operating on the field

### template-drive

```js
public name = "initial name";
```

or

```js
myMethod(): void {
    this.name = "initial name";
}
```

### reactive

```js
public nameControl = new FormControl("initial name");
```

or

```js
myMethod(): void {
    this.nameControl.setValue("initial name");
}
```

For more info about input binding, you can visit the official Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview